# Define one Youtube-Player API for mulitple players

Tags: youtube-api

i decided to try to impplement youtube vidoes on my web using Youtube-Api. My idea was to place the videos inside a slider and create a "playlist" with this method. My first problem is that i would like to set-up the youtube api for multiple players, but i have no idea how when the player is defined as "ytplayer":

```
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer1',  {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      //videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
  }
</script>
```

is there any way to define the "ytplayer" for multiple players which would be named as; ytplayer1, ytplayer2, .... . The reason what iam asking this question is that i would like to place the player inside the  tags and also call the "videoID" within the div tags, somehow like this:

```
<div id="ytplayer1" src="M7lc1UVf-VE"></div>
```

is the solution above even possible "with some changes ofcourse"? To place the player within  and also call the videoID from there?

Iam new to these kind of scripting so any help would be great. I searched the net but didnt found any relevant answer to my problem.

T

Answer (score 0):

I impimented a play list style on my site, but was only on a single player.

I have not looked at the player for a while, but as memory serves, you can target players by name. You will need to use the java-api and api calls as well, not just a div.

**href= "javascript:loadNewVideo('M7lc1UVf-VE')"**
as a basic example.

If you want to look at my site and open the code sourcs [***CLICK HERE***](http://www.youtubetutsite.com/)

Other help sections:
[***YouTube Api ref***](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

A good help refferance is this [***youtube forum***](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata?hl=en). It no longer is used for questions, but it is full of old questions and answers.